flutter bug plugins require a higher anoroid sdk version
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\Saddam ahmad\Desktop\vpn-basic-project\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 34
...
}
how to remove to run sussesfully app

Do the following changes to your project

Go to C:\Users\Saddam ahmad\Desktop\vpn-basic-project\android\app\build.gradle
Change the below code and re-run your application

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.appid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

